# How do I copy a pdf file to a temporary file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to make a temporary copy of the pdf file, show it and delete it after a while.
Now I do so:

```
content = File.open(pdf).read # in pdf i have path to original pdf
locale_file = Tempfile.open('whatever.pdf')
locale_file.write content
locale_file.flush
```

But the temporary pdf is empty. How to fix?

I need a copy of the original pdf in a temporary file.

**UPD**

```
content = File.open(pdf).read
locale_file = Tempfile.open('whatever.pdf')
locale_file.write content
locale_file.rewind
```

Comment: how did you read it? try locale_file.rewind; puts IO.read(locale_file.path). you need to reset the file descriptor

Comment: thanks, i do it, but it doesn't work too

Comment: can you share the rest of the code?

Comment: update question body

Comment: "But the temporary pdf is empty" where is the relevant code to that?